# live video streaming - cross platform - scalable

Tags: video-streaming, cdn, live-streaming

I'm trying to design a web application for live streaming of webcam video to a large number of users on pcs and mobile phones. Looking at all the options for such streaming, I deduced the following possible approaches:

1). Stream video using streaming codec in HLS format to a Content Delivery Network like Akamai, and access the live stream through that CDN on any device.

2). Use an existing Streaming service (like Ustream) through their API - not sure if these services address the scalability issues.

Please suggest if these are viable options, or, if there is any known standard way or examples of going about this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to go for a CDN if you have viewers more than 1000 and if they are spread across multiple geographical locations. Akami, Globix, VitalStream, Brightcove, Livestream etc are all good. The more users you got, the cheaper will be your per-GB charge...